# Eclipse PDE: Open internal web browser in specific position

Tags: eclipse, browser, view, pde

I want to open the Eclipse internal Web browser programmatically on the right side of the editor area, regardless of the open perspective.

I have no problem doing it in the main editor area, but when I open the browser as (or inside) a View, it is opened at the bottom position.

How do I do that? So far I tried:
- PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getBrowserSupport().createBrowser
- create a view and call ShowView
- create a fast view and open it using org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions
but none of them gave me any control over the position.
I don't want to create my own perspective, because the browser I want to add must not change the user's environment.

Thanks for your help,
Yaron.

Comment: You write "_it is opened at the bottom position._" What exactly do you mean here? Is it the position of the cursor in the browser or the placement of the view on the workbench window? Or something else?

Comment: it is the placement of the view in (what is probably) the default position.

Comment: The best I got so far is the fast view. I want it opened on the right side, but it keeps opening on the left.